# Is there a way to do ROLLUP or CUBE in R like in sql?

Tags: sql, r, statistics

Is there a way to summarize data in R using functions like ROLLUP and CUBE in sql?

If so could someone point me in the direction of an example?

Comment: Could you show a minimal example of what you want to achieve, with some small data and expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Group By Rollup in R? (Like SQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169073/how-to-do-group-by-rollup-in-r-like-sql)

Comment: good question but terribly asked, I linked much better one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the builtin dataset `CO2` try this:

```
as.data.frame(addmargins(xtabs(uptake ~ Plant + Type + Treatment, CO2)))
```